# Crash on Halide::Func definition

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, halide

I have a little problem with getting image data from a cv::Mat to a Halide::Image. I'm working on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015 Community and using the downloadable binaries of Halide for Windows 32bit.
Example:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread(...); // read grayscale image
Halide::Buffer input_buffer( Halide::UInt(8), image.cols, image.rows, 1, 1, image.data, "input_image" );
Halide::Image< uint8_t > input( input_buffer );
Halide::Func clamped = Halide::BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge(input);
```

got the following error message

```
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

I also tried it with plain malloc of data and giving it to the Halid::Buffer but got same error. I suppose there is some problem with memory ownership, because this error can occur if you try to delete objects twice, but I'm not sure about this.
Is that a bug in Halide or I'm doing s.th. wrong?

EDIT: Callstack

```
msvcr120d.dll!000007feddd3082e()
msvcr120d.dll!000007feddd30196()
msvcr120d.dll!000007feddd2d1e5()
Halide.dll!000007feddf2b8c2()
Halide.dll!000007feddf2157d()
Halide.dll!000007feddf15678()
Halide.dll!000007feddf166e7()
Halide.dll!000007fede1d4db5()
Test.exe!Halide::Internal::Variable::make(Halide::Type type, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > name) Zeile 3255
Test.exe!Halide::Var::operator Halide::Expr() Zeile 5476
Test.exe!Halide::BoundaryConditions::Internal::func_like_to_func<Halide::Image<unsigned char> >(Halide::Image<unsigned char> func_like) Zeile 9187
Test.exe!Halide::BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge<Halide::Image<unsigned char> >(Halide::Image<unsigned char> func_like) Zeile 9247
```

Comment: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp is not a Halide piece of code. Could you point out to where the error originates ? Or provide the full callstack ?

Comment: I've edited the question with the callstack